# There's an error while typing the password on pgAdmin 4 PostgreSQL 10 Server

Tags: pgadmin-4, postgresql-10

This is the result that I get any time I enter the password that I created to enter the PostgreSQL 10 Server. I'm 100% sure that the password that I add is correct, but for some reason, this error always comes up and I can't enter the server. What should I do?

[image: 1]

Comment: “*Please, click on the blue text.*” Please, follow our guidelines and include all pertinent debugging information (the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem as a [mre], as well as all error messages) ***as text, in the body of the question itself***. Posting this important information within images decreases the likelihood that others will take the time to help you, as it’s not practical to transcribe this information in its entirety when you could easily copy and paste it. Please review [ask] and edit your question to better conform to the guidelines therein.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.